# Sorting an ndarray along a specific column

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an array of shape (64,128,5). I want to sort this array according to the values of 4th channel i.e. the values in the (:,:,4) channel. I tried vstacking the array into shape (64*128, 5) and then apply argsort() for the 4th column and then reshaping it back to (64,128,5) but that doesn't give me the correct values.
Can anybody guide me as to how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean `array = array.reshape(-1, 5)[np.argsort(array[..., 4].ravel())].reshape(array.shape)`?

Comment: @jdehesa nice, I would post it as an answer. Comment: you can use the `.argsort` method directly: `array[...].ravel().argsort()` .